# Why does the Laravel Pagination always show the same page?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, pagination

I am using a nginx-Server and Laravel 5.6 and wanted to use a Pagination for my table.

This is my nginx.conf:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args;
```

This is my Controller:

```
public function getAllLocations()
{
    $locations = Location::orderBy('name')->paginate(10);

    return view('home', ['locations' => $locations, 'success' => false]);
}
```

My view:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    @foreach($locations as $location)    
        <tr id="{{$location->id}}">    
            <td>{{$location->name}}</td>    
        </tr>
    @endforeach

    {{$locations->links()}}
```

When I am clicking on the next Page the link is changing, but the same data is shown. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your data have some html codes?

Comment: No. I think I found the error, but I don't know how to solve it. The problem is that nginx always creates a second question mark behind the URL: **?%3Fpage=3**. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: How about removing `$is_args` in your `nginx.conf:`?

Comment: I will try it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this line

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args;
```

You have `?` then `is_args`. [`is_args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_is_args) puts a `?` if there are args otherwise a blank string. So when you have args you are telling `nginx` to go to `/index.php??args` thus the double question marks.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an idea, why it is default in nginx?

Comment: I have not seen yours which I am assuming is just a typo. But there is a great number of ways to do things in `nginx` so can not say for sure.